# Notifying property change does not work without assigning new instance to property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Suppose i have property in a class

```
    private InfoDetail dialogInfo; 
    public InfoDetail DialogInfo
            {
                get
                {
                     return this.InfoDetail;
                }

                set
                {
                    this.InfoDetail = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
```

And i initialize it once. when i assign property of this like
`this.InfoDetail.Index = 2;` it did not notify and did not hit the breakpoint.but when i create new instance and assign to it it triggers, like

```
InfoDetail obj = new InfoDetail();
obj.index = 2;
this.InfoDetail = obj
```

is this the correct behavior or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: `DialogInfo` is the property that needs settings isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

> when I assign property of this like `this.InfoDetail.Index = 2;` it did not notify

This is the correct behavior. the value of `InfoDetail` property itself doesn't change, it is still the same instance as before, with a different value of Index though.

To send notifications about Index change, InfoDetail should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise PropertyChanged event in Index setter. Just like class does with "DialogInfo" property.

As a second option you can temporarily reset DialogInfo to null, and then restore previous value. In this case all bound properties from InfoDetail will update - twice.

```
var info = this.InfoDetail;
info.Index = 2;
this.InfoDetail = null;
this.InfoDetail = info;
```

Comment: there is a similar interface for collections: INotifyCollectionChanged. ObservableCollection<T> implements it and often used in view models. resetting collection to null and back can be costly. binding to ObservableCollection will update individual items (added/removed)

Comment: Hmm, just looked up my code. Problem was my list is repolpulated each time i click a button, but simply writing "List l = new List<Item>();" won't call the PropertyChanged-Event. Since i completly scrap the old list anyways, there shouldn't be much of a performance loss. However, I'll work with a CollectionChanged event from now on, if possible. thx for the info.